# Incorrect result checking for Fisher numbers

Tags: c, function, loops

## Program Details: Fisher Number

A Fisher number is an integer for which the product of its factors (including itself) is equal to the number's cube. For example, `12` is a Fisher number, because 12<sup>3</sup> = 2 x 3 x 4 x 6 x 12.

**Example:**

```
Input: 12  
Output: true (12<sup>3</sup> = 2 x 3 x 4 x 6 x 12)

Input: 8  
Output: false (8<sup>3</sup> != 2 x 4 x 8)
```

**Objectives:**

- Write a program to check if the user input is a Fisher number or not.
- Print all the Fisher numbers in a given range

---

**Here is my code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int ch, product = 1, cube, num, i, j, min, max;

// Check Function

void check() {
    int i;
    printf("Enter the Number to check whether It is Fisher or Not\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    cube = num * num * num;
    for(i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
        if(num % i == 0) {
            product = product * i;
        }
    }
    if(cube == product) {
        printf("It is a Fisher Number!\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("It is not a Fisher Number\n");
    }
}

// RANGE FUNCTION

void range() {
    printf("Enter the Minimum and Maximum value of Range\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &min, &max);
    for(i = min; i <= max; i++) {
        cube = i * i * i;
        for(j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            if(i % j == 0) {
                product = product * i;
            }
        }
        if(cube == product) {
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
    }
}

void main() {
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter Your Choice \n");
    printf("1 - Check Fisher Number \n");
    printf("2 - Display Fisher Numbers in a Range \n");
    scanf("%d", &ch);
    switch(ch) {
        case 1: check();
                break;
        case 2: range();
                break;
        default: printf("Enter Valid Choice \n");
    }
    getch();
}
```

**[*Output picture*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIN7r.png) and text:**

```
Enter Your Choice 
1 - Check Fisher Number 
2 - Display Fisher Numbers in a Range 
2
Enter the Minimum and Maximum value of Range
1 40
1
```

I am not getting the range output right. For example, if the range is set to 1 to 15, it only shows `1` which is wrong!

Comment: What error? Make sure you're including all relevant information.

Comment: I am not getting the range output right.
For Example, if range is set to 1 to 15, it only shows 1 which is wrong!

Comment: Please add your "for example" to the question, with appropriate formatting. Also, "which is wrong" is not enough - show the *expected* result as well.

Comment: You should read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Also, just as a general guideline for the future: when you have two functions that both need to perform the same nontrivial task (e.g., checking whether an integer is a Fisher number), write a third function called `IsFisherNumber` that they can both call, rather than implementing the algorithm twice. Your code will be easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: Thank you :) @JoeFarrell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should multiply by `j` here:

```
if(i%j == 0) {
    product = product * i;
}
```

It would be more obvious if you used more meaningful variable names than `i` and `j`.

You also need to reset `product` variable before the inner loop (why is it a global variable anyway? Don't you know they are evil?)

```
cube = i * i * i;
product = 1;
for(j=1;j<=i;j++) { ...
```